# Set a specific product page as the homepage or redirect on homepage

Tags: magento2

I am creating a shop with only one product. I want this product page to be the homepage, or instantly redirect to that product page when i visit the store. Any idea how?

I did find this option to set a homepage url:

[image]

But if i simply enter

> /product-sku.html

there then it won't work and my homepage returns a 404.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up creating a module and using the following code:

etc/frontend/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
<event name="controller_action_predispatch">
    <observer name="controller_action_predispatch" instance="BB\BB\Observer\ControllerPredispatch" />
</event>
</config>
```

Observer/ControllerPredispatch.php

```
<?php

namespace BB\BB\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;

class ControllerPredispatch implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface
     */
    protected $url;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http
     */
    protected $http;

    /** @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Session */
    protected $customerSession;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http $http
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http $http,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
    )
    {
        $this->url = $url;
        $this->http = $http;
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
    }

    /**
     * Manages redirect
     */
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        /**
         * Check if user logged in
         */
        if ($this->customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
            return;
        }

        if ($observer->getRequest()->getFullActionName() == 'cms_index_index') {
            /**
             * Redirect to login
             */
            $this->http->setRedirect($this->url->getUrl('bb-check-extension.html'), 301);
        }
    }
}
```

Code is created by SR: [Magento 2 : Redirect From Homepage to Login if not Logged](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/156786/magento-2-redirect-from-homepage-to-login-if-not-logged)

Answer (score 0):

There is actually an easier way, in the default web url put:

```
catalog/product/view/id/1
```

Where "1" is the id of your product you want to show. I have tested it and it's working.

Answer (score 0):

the second answer with catalog/product/view/id/1 will break your install both the front-end and the backend and you won't be able to change the value back

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/198864)